# Define custom iterator that calls function to passed element

Tags: c++, c++11

I am often writing code like the following (here int and double are just example, types are usually pointers)

```
std::vector<int> va {1 ,2, 3};
std::vector<double> vb;

bool valid(int i) { return i % 2 == 0;}

for(auto a : va)
   if (valid(a))
      vb.push_back(static_cast<double>(a));
```

Since we don't have `transform_if` I would like to know if there is a way to do this by definining some special iterator:

```
template<typename T>
struct inserterStaticCast
{
    // not sure what to put here...
}
```

Then I could write code like

```
std::vector<double> vc(a.size());
std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), inserterStaticCast<double>(vc), &valid);
```

I would also be interested in the `backInserterStaticCast` version.

Is this possible in C++11?

Thank you

A few clarifications...

I cannot use boost. And to again in this case int and double are just for illustration, in the general case I do need a cast, usually something like
`static_cast<derived *>(base_ptr)`.

Comment: [std::back_inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) does fine [see example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3e8d813936600c0)

Comment: You don't need a cast to convert `int` to `double`. Just use `std::copy_if` with an ordinary insert iterator: `std::copy_if(std::begin(va), std::end(va), std::back_inserter(vb), valid);`.

Comment: Are you actually asking about `vector<Base *> base = ...; vector<Derived *> derived;`  and wanting a `copy_if_derived(base, inserter(derived))`?

Comment: "int and double are just for illustration" -- yes, and what they illustrate apparently is **not the actual question**. So the code in the question is **wrong**, and you need to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want boost's [`function_output_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/function_output.html). In your example it would be

```
auto cast_back_iterator = make_function_output_iterator([&b](int i){ b.push_back(static_cast<double>(i)); });
std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), cast_back_iterator, valid);
```

Which makes more sense when there isn't an implicit conversion between the two types, such as with `Base *` -> `Derived *` conversion

Answer (score 1):

You can do filtering with `std::copy_if` and `std::back_inserter`:

```
std::vector<double> vc;
std::copy_if(va.begin(), va.end(), std::back_inserter(vc), valid);
```

Or use [`boost::range::adaptors::filtered`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/filtered.html) (same example problem as yours):

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>

#include <vector>

bool valid(int i) { return i % 2 == 0;}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> va {1 ,2, 3};

    using namespace boost::adaptors;
    auto vb = boost::copy_range<std::vector<double>>(va | filtered(valid));
}
```

Note that conversion of `int` to `double` is implicit and doesn't require a cast.

If you do need a conversion, just throw in [`transformed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html):

```
auto vb = boost::copy_range<std::vector<double>>(va
    | filtered(valid)
    | transformed([](int a) { return static_cast<double>(a); })
    );
```

Comment: Oops, just noticed that you cannot use boost.

Comment: Actually boost seems to have really cool things. I would be glad to use this if I could.